# Meteor - Blaze easy-search template - how to insert input field attributes into template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-easy-search

So I have an easy-search template:

```
<template name="searchBox">

    <div class="">
        {{> EasySearch.Autosuggest index=PlayersIndex }}
    </div>

</template>
```

And I'd like to make the input field look like this (have the following attributes):

```
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type to add new player"
            ref="textInput"
          />
```

I've tried adding the attributes to the argument but that doesn't seem to work:

```
        {{> EasySearch.Autosuggest index=PlayersIndex type="text"}}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `attributes` property in your HTML:

```
{{> EasySearch.Input index=index attributes=inputAttributes}}
```

And in your JS, fill it with your needed data:

```
`Template.leaderboard.helpers({
    inputAttributes: function () {
        return { 'class': 'easy-search-input', 'placeholder': 'Start searching...' };
    }
)}
`
```

I was able to find the answer by looking at this [repo](https://github.com/matteodem/easy-search-leaderboard), so make sure to check github repos as they might contain helpful examples. ;)